# 403 ForbiddenYou don't have permission to access /wp-admin/install.php on this server

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm working with chef on ubuntu 14.04 desktop 64 virtual machine. I installed Apache, MySQL, php and wordpress based on your tutorial, but I don't have right test results. I have this result:" 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/install.php on this server". Help!!!

Comment: Start by checking the file permissions. Does the http server process really have read access to the scripts and all the folders in the path?

Comment: There may be a .htaccess file with something along the lines of `Options -Indexes` that could be limiting you.